# A does something over something

Tags: prepositions

[SOAP](https://www.guru99.com/soap-simple-object-access-protocol.html)

> SOAP is an XML-based protocol for accessing web services **over** HTTP.

'Over' here means "based on" or "not based on"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Over" here means "by means of" or "using".

- Can you repeat it over the comlink.
- Files can be sent over the internet.
- You can upload files to the server over FTP.

This seems to be mainly used in IT.